# context.Request.User is null in OWIN OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: iis, oauth, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement OAuth using OWIN for a Web API v2 endpoint on my local intranet.  The API is hosted in IIS using built-in Windows Authentication.  In short, this is what I want to happen.

**When I ask for my Token at /token**

1. Pull the WindowsPrincipal out of the OWIN context
2. Use the SID from the WindowsPrincipal to look up some roles for this
   user in a SQL table.
3. Create a new ClaimsIdentity that stores the username and roles
4. Turn that into a Json Web Token (JWT) that I sent bak

**When I request a resource from my API using my token**

1. Convert the JWT Bearer token back to the ClaimsIdentity
2. Use that ClaimsIdentity for authorizing requests to the resource by
   role
3. This way I don't have to do a database lookup for user roles on each
   request.  It's just baked into the JWT.

I think I'm setting everything up correctly.  My Startup.Configuration method looks like this.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    // token generation
    // This is what drives the action when a client connects to the /token route
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        // for demo purposes
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,

        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8),
        AccessTokenFormat = GetMyJwtTokenFormat(),
        Provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider()
    });



    //// token consumption
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(
        new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Realm = "http://www.ccl.org",
            Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = GetMyJwtTokenFormat()
        }
    );


    app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());

}
```

MyAuthorizationServerProvider looks like this...

```
    public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            // Since I'm hosting in IIS with Windows Auth enabled
            // I'm expecting my WindowsPrincipal to be here, but it's null  :(
            var windowsPrincipal = context.OwinContext.Request.User.Identity;

            // windowsPrincipal is null here.  Why?

            // Call SQL to get roles for this user

            // create the identity with the roles
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(stuff, more stuff);

            context.Validated(id);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that context.Request.User is null here.  I can't get to my WindowsPrincipal.  If I create some other dummy middleware, I can get to the WindowsPrincipal without issue.  Why is it null in this context?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Swap the order of UseOAuthAuthorizationServer and UseOAuthBearerAuthentication. UseOAuthBearerAuthentication calls `UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);` to make it (and everything before it) run earlier in the ASP.NET pipeline. User is null when you run during the Authenticate stage.

Comment: Thanks!  This did the trick.  Sorry for the late response. I appreciate you taking the time to answer.  This was a huge help.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I've spent almost a day looking for this!!