# How to manually set the current user in the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider' GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity

I have an asp.net mvc webapi 2 project and I'm using the new asp.net identity infrastructure with owin and oauth and all its great features...

I'm using for authorization the token based system: `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);`

Everything works great, the only issue that I have is the following - in my own `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation, in the method `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` (the one that gets called once an user wants to authenticate by visiting the /token url), after checking the user validity and other things, I need to call other methods (recalculate shopping cart, etc) but those methods (don't ask why) looks into the current context `User` to get the username and role of the user, but during the running of the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method, the current context `User` is null (is somehow normal - I'm not asking why).

My question is: in order to not break any guidelines of using the oAuth bearer tokens authorization is it OK to manually set the user in this method like this?

`context.Request.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(oAuthIdentity);`

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

in owin startup orders of bearer and authorization must be like this

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions());
```

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25045119/3667938)